# Add paragraph-wise wordcount to compiled PDF

Tags: word-count

I would like to add a paragraph or section-wise wordcount to the compiled PDF output of a `.tex` file. Is there anything that makes this possible?

I'm aware of some of the options for finding the total wordcount, but I'm specifically interested in the number of words written within a specific section, subsection, or paragraph.

Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: You can  use an enviroment counted: http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=20289&p=67511#p67511

Comment: [TeXcount](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/) can give you summary counts per section/subsection, but relies on identifying the macros that initiate a new section for this and so will not do it per paragraph. Since TeXcount runs separately from LaTeX - it's a Perl script - it will give a list of sections, but will not merge this into the document. It is, however, possible to write the output from TeXcount to file, and import this into the document. The [FAQ](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/faq.html) gives some suggestions on how to do this. Thus, at best, it provides a partial solution.